# mail function is not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i have customized my WordPress using PHP and include some PHP file in WordPress has template but the mail function is not working there please help me out

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $ip, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: You're missing a lot of code

Comment: same code i tried in one more site but it is working fine there but in wordpress issue arise

Comment: `mail` has nothing to do with WP, it's an internal PHP function http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php You might wanna check your setup.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php this code only i use in php it works but it not works in WP

Comment: have you tried this code: <?php wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments ); ?>

Comment: you can take help from http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail

Comment: <?php wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments ); ?> als not works

Answer (score 0):

Try to use wordpress inbuilt function wp_mail()

**Documentation**
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail

Then wit filters you can change "from" and "from name"

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail_from
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail_from_name

**if this does not work, then it is time to check server set up...**

Comment: server setup what will be the issue